# Finding angles of triangle by given sides in C programming

Tags: c, math

I run it in my code::blocks to show 3 angles of triangle where 3 sides are given by the user. But if I run and give 3 sides such as 3,4,5 output will be -1.#J -1.#J -1.#J. What's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float a, b, c, A, B, C, R, s, pi, area;
    pi = acos(-1);

    scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);
    s = (a+b+c)/2;
    area = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));

    R = (a*b*c)/(4*area);

    A = (180/pi)*asin(a/2*R);
    B = (180/pi)*asin(b/2*R);
    C =  (180/pi)*asin(c/2*R);

    printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f", A, B, C);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First observation: stop using `float` unless *absolutely necessary* - we have 21st century computers now. `sqrt()` and the trig functions return a `double` value. Do you use `short` when `int` would be the norm?

Comment: @MusfiqRifat what have you tried.

Comment: Are you really entering your input separated with commas? That's not what your `scanf` is expecting.

Comment: Since `PI` is defined in the math.h header file, why are you using: `pi = acos(-1);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need more parentheses.  You have:

```
A = (180/pi)*asin(a/2*R);
```

You need:

```
A = (180/pi)*asin(a/(2*R));
```

What you wrote is equivalent to:

```
A = (180 / pi) * asin((R * a) / 2);
```

You should also check your inputs so that a 'triangle' with sides 1, 1, 3 is rejected, for example.  Negative and zero lengths should probably be rejected too.

#### Revised code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a, b, c, A, B, C, R, s, pi, area;
    pi = acos(-1);

    if (scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c) != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read 3 numbers\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Sides must be strictly positive\n");
        return 1;
    }
    s = (a + b + c) / 2;
    if (a > s || b > s || c > s)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "The three sides %.2f, %.2f, %.2f do not form a triangle\n",
                a, b, c);
        return 1;
    }

    area = sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));

    R = (a * b * c) / (4 * area);

    A = (180 / pi) * asin(a / (2 * R));
    B = (180 / pi) * asin(b / (2 * R));
    C = (180 / pi) * asin(c / (2 * R));

    printf("Sides:  %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n", a, b, c);
    printf("Angles: %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n", A, B, C);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that error messages are reported on standard error.  All lines of output end with a newline in the format.  The input data is echoed.  All of these are good practices.

#### Example runs

```
$ triangle <<< "0 1 3"
Sides must be strictly positive
$ triangle <<< "-1 1 3"
Sides must be strictly positive
$ triangle <<< "1 1 3"
The three sides 1.00, 1.00, 3.00 do not form a triangle
$ triangle <<< "3 4 5"
Sides:    3.00   4.00   5.00
Angles:  36.87  53.13  90.00
$ triangle <<< "3 3 3"
Sides:    3.00   3.00   3.00
Angles:  60.00  60.00  60.00
$ triangle <<< "1 1.4141 1"
Sides:    1.00   1.41   1.00
Angles:  45.00    nan  45.00
$ triangle <<< "1 1 1.4141"
Sides:    1.00   1.00   1.41
Angles:  45.00  45.00    nan
$ triangle <<< "1 1 1.414"
Sides:    1.00   1.00   1.41
Angles:  45.01  45.01  89.98
$ triangle <<< "1 1 1.41421356237309504880"
Sides:    1.00   1.00   1.41
Angles:  45.00  45.00    nan
$
```

I'm a little puzzled about the `nan` values.  However, changing the data type from `float` to `double` and adjusting the `scanf()` formats appropriately (`%lf` instead of `%f`) seems to 'resolve' (maybe 'evade' is a better word) that problem.

Comment: Perhaps your `nan` are due to `asin(1.000...1)`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34110514/2410359)

Comment: Minor: IMO, "zero" lengths should "work" too, but those are corner cases.

Comment: @chux: All lengths zero is indeterminate; two lengths zero isn't a triangle; one length zero requires the other sides to be equal.  On the whole, rejecting zeros seems best.

Comment: A length can be non-zero, yet scan as zero as it is tiny.  Code that copes with zero better handles these minutes values too.  Of course for simple exercises, code working in the extremes is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
A = (180/pi)*asin(a/(2*R));
```

rather than

```
A = (180/pi)*asin(a/2*R);
```

Insufficient parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Additional detail:

`asin(x)` is only defined for values `[-1.0 ... 1.0]`.  With select input, corrected code may get a `a/(2*R)` that is just a little bit greater than 1.0 due to calculation issues with floating point.

```
s = (a+b+c)/2;

//  Jonathan Leffler tests

area = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
R = (a*b*c)/(4*area);

// add test
double R2 = R*2.0;
A = (a>R2) ? 180/pi : (180/pi)*asin(a/R2);
...
```

Comment: Yes, the 'nan' values I got are almost certainly due to inaccuracies in the float arithmetic.  At the point where you need to write the code you did three times, it becomes desirable to use a function — maybe an inline function — rather than writing the conditionals out three times.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get your posted code to work, even given all the comments and prior answers.

However, this works very well.

Note: I did not include code to error check the call to `scanf()` to keep the presentation simple

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define RAD_2_DEG  (57.2958)
#define TOTAL_DEG  (180.0)

int main( void )
{

    int  a, b, c;   // user entered lengths of sides of triangle
    double A, B, C; // calculated angle values in degrees

    scanf( "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c );


    // note: acos returns the angle in radians
    //       and one radian is (approx) 57.2958 degrees
    A = RAD_2_DEG * acos((double)(b*b + c*c - a*a)/(2.0*b*c));

    B = RAD_2_DEG * acos((double)(c*c + a*a - b*b)/(2.0*a*c));

    // third angle done this way to absorb fractional degree errors
    C = TOTAL_DEG -(A + B);

    printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f", A, B, C);
    return 0;
}
```